# How to Evenly Space Icons and Text Inside a RichText Widget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, android-studio, layout, richtext

I'm working on a Flutter application using Dart and I've encountered a specific UI design challenge. My goal is to achieve a layout where icons and text are evenly spaced within a `RichText` widget. Below are images illustrating my current design and the desired outcome.

**Current Design:**

[image]

**Desired Outcome:**

[image]

As illustrated, I'm trying to separate the icons and text to match the desired layout. However, I've been unable to add spacing within the `RichText` widget to achieve this effect.

Here's the code snippet I'm working with:

```
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
  children: [
    RichText(
      text: TextSpan(
        style: GoogleFonts.questrial(),
        children: [
          WidgetSpan(
            child: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.checkDouble,
                size: 40,
                color: Color(0xffD7D7D7)),
          ),
          TextSpan(
              text: "Timer",
              style: GoogleFonts.questrial(
                textStyle: TextStyle(
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                  color:Color(0xff3B3B3B),
                ),
              )
          ),
          WidgetSpan(
            child: Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.squareXmark,
                size: 40,
                color: Color(
                    0xffD7D7D7)),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
```

I've attempted to modify the `TextSpan` and `WidgetSpan` elements to include padding or margin, but neither seem applicable in this context. Additionally, I've reviewed similar questions and documentation but haven't found a solution that applies to spacing within a `RichText` widget.

How can I add space between the icons and the text in this `RichText` widget to achieve the desired layout?

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: why you wrap them into `RichText ` as a `Row`  children? 
you can remove the `RichText` and set alignment to spaceevenly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of RichText please use Row like

```dart
Row(         
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
children: [                                   
  Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.checkDouble,size: 40, color: Color(0xffD7D7D7)),
 Text("Timer", textStyle: TextStyle(                                                 
  fontSize: 20,
  fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,                         
  color:Color(0xff3B3B3B),
 ),                                               
),
Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.squareXmark, size: 40,                                             color: Color(0xffD7D7D7)),
],
),
```